# Tailscale list all devices using api

Tags: tailscale

I am trying to follow the tailscale documentation to list all devices on my network using exposed API [here](https://github.com/tailscale/tailscale/blob/main/api.md#getdevices)

In the example it says that I need to provide tailnet name

```
GET /api/v2/tailnet/example.com/devices
curl 'https://api.tailscale.com/api/v2/tailnet/example.com/devices' \
  -u "tskey-yourapikey123:"
```

when I replace example.com with my tailnet name I got from DNS tab on my admin page I am getting this error response

```
403 Forbidden
{
    "message": "user tailnet does not match"
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and how shall I get my list of devices to see which of them is online/offline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name that's displayed on the DNS settings page is for hostnames (it's of the form `something.ts.net`), it is not meant for API calls.

The tailnet name for API calls is the identifier for your user (for single-person tailnets) or domain -- it't shown on the [General settings page](https://login.tailscale.com/admin/settings/general) as the "Organization".

Even simpler, you can use `-` as a shorthand for the requesting user's default tailnet. [The documentation](https://github.com/tailscale/tailscale/blob/main/api.md#tailnet) covers some of this, but it could be made clearer.